I cannot get r100 to find any networks
I have a new canon r100 and when trying to set up WIFI it will not find any network.

What are you expecting to happen? Have you followed the instructions exactly as in the manual?

If your wifi network is 5 GHz, the R100 cannot connect to it. The wi-fi capability in the R100 can only use wifi on the 2.4 GHz band.
